# How to calculate prediction Intervals for a sum of predicted values from a mixed-effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, prediction, prediction-interval

I have a mixed-effects regression model and have predicted values with their respective prediction intervals. I would like to obtain the sum of these predicted values, and create a prediction interval for this sum.

This question [The "sum" of prediction intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14987/the-sum-of-prediction-intervals) asks something similar, but are there any additional considerations when using bootstrapped predictions from a mixed model?

For example, using `merTools::predictInterval` and the following reproducible code gives a list of bootstrapped predicted values. If I sum these, how do I create a prediction interval for this value?

```
library(lme4)
library(merTools)

set.seed(271828)
data(sleepstudy)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
summary(fm1)

predictInterval(merMod = fm1, newdata = sleepstudy, 
                level = 0.95, n.sims = 1000,
                stat = "median", type="linear.prediction",
                include.resid.var = TRUE)
```